# Rails create dynamic attributes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-5, rails-activerecord

I'm trying to make e-commerce shop with RoR. Most of the required functionality I did without any problems, but now I really need somebody's help here.

I want to make product attributes, like a "Size", "Weight", "Color", etc.
Easiest way is to define this attributes in model migration, but now I want to make attributes dynamic. The main problem is that I can't get all params with attributes from forms when trying to create product.

products/new.html.erb

```
<%= form_for @product, url: admin_products_path(@product) do |f| %>
  <%= f.label :name, 'Name' %>
  <%= f.text_field :name, class: "form-control" %>
  <%= text_field_tag "product[product_feature][]" %>
  <%= text_field_tag "product[product_feature][]" %>
  <%= f.submit "Submit" %>
<% end %>
```

So, I want to generate many fields with attribute name and value, fill them and use these params in controller to interate them and finally create product attributes.

Like

```
params[:product_features].each do |k, v|
  ProductFeature.create(name: k, value: v, product_id: product_id)
end
```

All gems, that can manipulate with dynamic attributes aren't working with Rails 5+, so I need to find solution for this problem.

I even have working simple db solution for this, but it's uncomfortable to create params. Here it is.

**Product.rb**

```
class Product < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :product_features
  has_many :features, :through => :product_features
end
```

**ProductFeature.rb**

```
class ProductFeature < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :product
  belongs_to :feature
end
```

**Feature.rb**

```
class Feature < ApplicationRecord
end
```

Comment: Sounds to me like a nested attributes can solve this http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/NestedAttributes/ClassMethods.html

Answer (score 1):

Make a new model, a child of product called ProductAttribute with two attributes.

```rb
Class ProductAttribute < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :product

  validates :name, presence: true
  validates :value, presence: true
end
```

Then use [cocoon](https://github.com/nathanvda/cocoon), or just [`accepts_nested_attributes`](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/NestedAttributes/ClassMethods.html)

```rb
class Product < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :product_attributes, as: :attributes
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :attributes, allow_destroy: true
end
```

```rb
class ProductsController < ApplicationController
.
.
.
  private
  .
  .
  def product_params
    params.require(:product).permit(. . . attributes_attributes: [:id, :name, :value])
  end
end
```

Cocoon is definitely what you're looking for.

Answer (score -2):

Heres a quick example i found

```
class Product
      belongs_to :collection
    end

    class Collection
      has_many :products
    end
```

and then in your view something like this

```
<%= collection_select(:product, :collection_id, Collection.all, :id, :name) %>
```